# How can I remove this single hole American Standard bathroom faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I see no screw and it doesn't seem to be attached at the bottom. How do I remove this leaky faucet to get to the washers?[image][image]

Comment: try to find a service manual or a parts diagram (exploded view) on the web ...... those taps disassemble from the top ..... take off the handle and the top cap, and work your way down ..... there probably is a retainer of some kind under the top cap .....  the cartridge should pull up. out of the faucet body

Comment: You don't need to remove the faucet to replace the cartridge. Look on the top cap on the back and see if there's a hole or small plug. If there is most likely there is an allen set screw in the hole or behind the plug that you loosen to remove the top cap.

Answer (score 2):

Your nuts are right here:
[image: bottom side of the faucet with nuts highlighted]

The threaded bolts are attached to the faucet, and if you unscrew thenuts, you can remove it. The nuts are longer than usual ones, presumably so that you can get a reasonable grip in a narrow space.